# Print all formats of now()

Tags: python

I would like to see examples of the different formattings available with something akin to the following:

```
>>> for d in dir(datetime.datetime.now()):
...  print("\n"+d)
...  print(getattr(datetime.datetime.now(), d))
```

However, `getattr()` returns only a description of the object, not the value (even when wrapped in `str()`):

```
>>> getattr(datetime.datetime.now(), 'isoformat')
<built-in method isoformat of datetime.datetime object at 0x020B41A0>
```

So how could I concoct the equivalent of this with `isoformat()` being dynamically added:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
'2013-11-25T15:01:09.075919'
```

Must I resort to `eval()`?

Comment: The various methods shown by `dir` for a datetime have on the whole nothing whatsoever to do with formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't store it anywhere, it prints the representation. `getattr` actually returns the object you want:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> isoformat = getattr(datetime.datetime.now(), 'isoformat')
>>> isoformat()
'2013-11-25T20:05:57.262055'
```

While what're you doing is just printing the string representation:

```
>>> print(isoformat)
<built-in method isoformat of datetime.datetime object at 0x0000000002F66D50>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
 d = dir(datetime.datetime.now())
 for i in d:
   if not i.startswith('_'):  # Skip private members
      m = getattr(datetime.datetime.now(), i) # Get the method
      print i,  # Print the name
      try:      # some will not work without more info or at all.
        print m()
      except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Should give you a good start.  On python 2.6 the above code gives:

```
astimezone Required argument 'tz' (pos 1) not found
combine Required argument 'date' (pos 1) not found
ctime Mon Nov 25 13:23:18 2013
date 2013-11-25
day 'int' object is not callable
dst None
fromordinal fromordinal() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
fromtimestamp Required argument 'timestamp' (pos 1) not found
hour 'int' object is not callable
isocalendar (2013, 48, 1)
isoformat 2013-11-25T13:23:18.190000
isoweekday 1
max 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
microsecond 'int' object is not callable
min 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
minute 'int' object is not callable
month 'int' object is not callable
now 2013-11-25 13:23:18.195000
replace 2013-11-25 13:23:18.195000
resolution 'datetime.timedelta' object is not callable
second 'int' object is not callable
strftime Required argument 'format' (pos 1) not found
strptime strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
time 13:23:18.198000
timetuple time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=13, tm_min=23, tm_sec=18, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=329, tm_isdst=-1)
timetz 13:23:18.199000
today 2013-11-25 13:23:18.199000
toordinal 735197
tzinfo 'NoneType' object is not callable
tzname None
utcfromtimestamp utcfromtimestamp() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
utcnow 2013-11-25 13:23:18.202000
utcoffset None
utctimetuple time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=13, tm_min=23, tm_sec=18, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=329, tm_isdst=0)
weekday 0
year 'int' object is not callable
```